# Swap and replace number in text file C#

Tags: c#, text, replace

Update question:

I have XML 12 file with each file contains a serial number as shown below

```
File XML1 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_1

File XML2 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_2

File XML3 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_3

File XML4 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_4

File XML5 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_5

File XML6 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_6

File XML7 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_7

File XML8 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_8
File XML9 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_9

File XML10 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_10

File XML11 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_11

File XML12 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_12
```

I want each serial number to be replaced like below result:
I extracted that serial number and tried using *substring* to cut the last 2 numbers instead but it is not really good because the serial number is not fixed.

```
File XML1 serial number:
T6115393670110-44

File XML2 serial number:
T6115393670210-44

File XML3 serial number:
T6115393670310-44

File XML4 serial number:
T6115393670410-44

File XML5 serial number:
T6115393670510-44

File XML6 serial number:
T6115393670010-44_6

File XML7 serial number:
T6115393670710-44

File XML8 serial number:
T6115393670810-44

File XML9 serial number:
T6115393670910-44

File XML10 serial number:
T6115393671010-44

File XML11 serial number:
T6115393671110-44

File XML12 serial number:
T6115393671210-44
```

and i try code get serialnumber:

```
 string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(txtSource.Text, "*.xml");
            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
 XElement BoardTestXMLExport = doc.Root;
 XNamespace ns1 = BoardTestXMLExport.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ns1");
          int numberOfComponentsTested = (int)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("numberOfComponentsTested");
                    DateTime testerTestStartTime = (DateTime)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("testerTestStartTime");
                    DateTime testTime = (DateTime)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("testTime");
                    string testStatus = (string)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("testStatus");
                    DateTime testerTestEndTime = (DateTime)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("testerTestEndTime");
                    XElement BoardXML = BoardTestXMLExport.Element(ns1 + "BoardXML");
                    string serialNumber = (string)BoardXML.Attribute("serialNumber");
             }
     /// * do something here
}
```

Is there a solution for doing this? please help me. thanks!

Comment: If you have total commander or similar, use regex rename. Much easier

Comment: Why is substring not a good way?

Comment: @Divisadero will total commander be able to alter file contents? or is it just filenames only?

Comment: @phuzi "Rename files" functions is only to rename files.

Comment: @Divisadero OP is asking to edit contents of a file(s) not rename them

Comment: @phuzi yep, I am blind as a bat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the file, modify content and write back to file (I assumed that numbers will be no more than 2 digits, as place where you want to insert that numbers is only two characters):

```
// read all lines
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
// modify content
lines = lines
    .Select(l =>
    {
        var code = l.Substring(0, l.LastIndexOf('_'));
        var number = l.Substring(l.LastIndexOf('_') + 1).PadLeft(2, '0');
        return code.Remove(10, 2).Insert(10, number);
    }).ToArray();
// write back to file
File.WriteAllLines(pathToFile, lines);
```

Comment: I think there's more to it than that: the numbers after the _ have to be inserted in the main string

Comment: @auburg Yes, missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Regular expression* is an alternative to substring (esp. when we have complex transformation):

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  static string Transform(string line) => Regex.Replace(
      line,
    @"(?<prefix>T[0-9]{9,})(?<remove>0{2})(?<suffix>[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(?<num>_[0-9]+)$",
      m => m.Groups["prefix"].Value +
           m.Groups["num"].Value.TrimStart('_').PadLeft(2, '0') + 
           m.Groups["suffix"].Value);
```

Then

```
  string fileName = @"c:\myFile"; 

  File.WriteAllLines(fileName, File
    .ReadLines(fileName)
    .Select(line => Transform(line))
    .ToArray());
```